# getline() and stringstream errors in c++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I was working on some basic code but had problems with my getline() function. I was using a while loop to go through a stringstream like this:

```
    while (N > -1){
        getline(cin, s);
        stringstream ss(s);
        
      while (getline(ss, n, ",")){
            num.push_back(n); 
      }
```

I always go this warning saying
“no instance of overloaded function “getline” matches the argument list —- argument types are:(std::stringstream, int, const char[2])”

I thought it was my code that was the problem, but when I tried copying and pasting Geeks for geeks code into visual studio code  I got a similar message.

Here’s their code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    string str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"; 
    vector<string> v; 
  
    stringstream ss(str); 
  
    while (ss.good()) { 
        string substr; 
        getline(ss, substr, ', '); 
        v.push_back(substr); 
    } 
  
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) 
        cout << v[i] << endl; 
}
```

I’ve also seen a YouTuber, Derek Banas, do something similar in his recent C++ tutorial. When I try to copy him, I always get an error.

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- So the youtube video shows to use this header?  This is why it isn't a good idea to learn C++ from videos that have not been peer-reviewed.

Comment: To understand the duplicates better, I guess you're on a POSIX system (e.g. Linux or macOS) which have a *different* [`getline`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) function in the global namespace. By including that header-file you also get the header fie declaring that POSIX function, and the `using` statement then pulls in the `std::getline` overloads into the same global namespace, making them all clash.

Comment: Please always post the *full* error message. Your code uses `', '`, a comma then a space, which is not a valid character. Get rid of the extra space character.

Comment: Pretty sure this was closed for the wrong reason.  It has nothing to do with bits/std++.h and using namespace std.  It *is* a typo, since the `getline` call passes ", ".

Comment: Also, please make your questions consistent. The first snippet of code doesn't match the other code you show. The first snippet also uses the wrong single quotes. Please copy-paste properly.

Comment: @StephenNewell The [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function have overloads using both characters and strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agreed, which is why I think this should be closed as a typo, not a duplicate.

Comment: To the OP (that's you Becky B) please [edit] your question to include a single [mcve], and a complete and full copy-paste (as text) of the build output.

Comment: I’ve fixed the first example. The reason they aren’t exactly the same is because the first one is my code and the second is one I found online. I no longer have problems with the code I found online after taking your advice, but I still get problems with mine.

Comment: Also for my code, I wasn’t using the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` so I don’t think that was the problem.